# Select from table and function

Tags: sql, oracle, function, ora-00932

I have a function that returns a table.  The returned table contains (among other things) a store_id.  I can get the store_id for a particular transaction_id and city_id as follows:

```
select store_id from table(user2.f_get_store(15, 12345)); 
--where 15 and 12345 are city_id and transation_id
```

I have another table that contains a list of transactions (which includes transaction_id and city_id).  I want a query that returns

```
store_id, city_id, transaction_id
```

for every entry in the transaction table.  My first guess was:

```
select user2.f_get_store(city_id, transaction_id), city_id, transaction_id
from table_name;
```

(simplified away the unimportant details)

However, this yields an "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes" error.  How do I need to structure this query?

(I'm using Oracle)

~~~~~EDIT~~~~~

When I try

```
select user2.f_get_store(city_id, transactioN_id) from table_name;
```

I get insufficient privileges error.  I presume this is because f_get_store is owned by a different user than the one I am using.

(I edited the example code to show the function being owned by a different user)

Comment: have you tried using a cast on the return types?

Comment: Agree with AJ.  I don't know why your id fields would be chars, but that seems to be what it implies.  Do you get same error when you do "select f_get_store(city_id, transaction_id) from table" ?

Comment: Probably either city_id or transaction_id is being treated like a string and implicitly being converted to a number - then bombing... To be more useful you should post the complete error message (hint on which type of conversion) and perhaps the code of the function.

Comment: Complete error:  `ORA-00932: inconsistent dataypes: expected - got USER2.F_GET_STORE_TYPE_TABLE
00932. 00000 - "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*cause:
*action:
Error at Line: 13 Column 4"

Comment: @AJ's first comment.  Can you be more specific?  Casting the return of the function, or what is being passed in?

Comment: I would try casting the values going into the function - maybe one of the parameters is being treated as a number instead of a string? or the reverse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a scalar subquery:

```
select (select store_id from table(user2.f_get_store(city_id, transaction_id))) store_id, city_id, transaction_id
from table_name;
```

Comment: Will that work using user2.f_get_store(city_id, transation_id) instead of hardcoding the 15, 12345?

Comment: Oops -- that's what I meant, just forgot to change the values when I copied your original query.  Edited to show the final version.